# nth non-Fibonacci number

Tags: java, fibonacci, number-theory

how to find nth non-Fibonacci number in o(logn)
non-Fibonacci number are : 4,6,7,9,10....
below function gives non-Fibonacci number for given value of n

```
static int nonFibonacci(int n){
    int a=1,b=2,c=3;
    while(n>0){
        a=b;
        b=c;
        c=a+b;
        n-=(a-1);
    }
    n+=(a-1);
    return (n+b);
}
```

it gives correct answer but i want to optimize it, Using matrix multiplication one can find Fibonacci number in o(logn) how to apply that property to find nth non-fibonacci number.

Comment: This is O(log n), I believe, due to the exponential distribution of the Fibonacci sequence.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm in your snippet is not `O(n)` because the Fibonacci series grows exponentially. Thus, it will take you `O(log n)` steps to get bigger than n. The following (and very simple "benchmark") seems to confirm your code already has the right complexity :

```
public class Benchmark {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long n = 2;
        for (int i=0 ; i<62 ; i++, n *= 2) {
            long executionTimeNanos = timedExecution(n);
            System.out.println(n + " " + executionTimeNanos + " " + executionTimeNanos/Math.log(n));
        }
    }

    private static long timedExecution(long n) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        nonFibonacci(n);
        return System.nanoTime() - start;
    }

    private static long nonFibonacci(long n) {
        long a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
        while (n > 0) {
            a = b;
            b = c;
            c = a + b;
            n -= (a - 1);
        }
        n += (a - 1);
        return (n + b);
    }
}
```

Output :

```
2 3421 4935.459734881144
4 2566 1850.97773746054
8 855 411.16808665335464
16 2566 925.48886873027
32 1283 370.195547492108
64 855 205.58404332667732
128 1283 264.4253910657915
256 1283 231.3722171825675
512 856 137.21632833343918
1024 1283 185.097773746054
2048 1711 224.40465590554695
4096 1711 205.70426791341805
8192 1283 142.38290288158
16384 1710 176.2148942800091
32768 1283 123.39851583070268
65536 1283 115.68610859128376
131072 1283 108.88104338003177
262144 1710 137.05602888445154
524288 1711 129.91848499794824
1048576 1283 92.548886873027
2097152 1710 117.47659618667274
4194304 1711 112.20232795277347
8388608 1710 107.26123999652728
16777216 1711 102.85213395670903
33554432 1711 98.73804859844066
67108864 1710 94.88494307385106
134217728 1710 91.37068592296768
268435456 2138 110.16007133645014
536870912 2138 106.36144818691737
1073741824 1711 82.28170716536722
2147483648 2138 99.49941927163238
4294967296 2566 115.68610859128376
8589934592 2138 93.46915143698799
17179869184 2993 126.99959580531375
34359738368 2565 105.72893656800545
68719476736 2138 85.68005548390566
137438953472 2566 100.0528506735427
274877906944 2566 97.41988091897579
549755813888 6415 237.30483813596666
1099511627776 2138 77.11204993551509
2199023255552 2566 90.29159694929464
4398046511104 2138 73.44004755763342
8796093022208 2566 86.09198778886233
17592186044416 2566 84.13535170275182
35184372088832 2566 82.26567722046845
70368744177664 2566 80.47729293306696
140737488355328 2566 78.76501010470383
281474976710656 2565 77.09401624750399
562949953421312 2566 75.55011173308327
1125899906842624 2994 86.38857904843113
2251799813685248 2994 84.69468534159914
4503599627370496 2993 83.03819725732053
9007199254740992 2994 81.498659479652
18014398509481984 5132 137.10946203411407
36028797018963968 2994 78.53507186221012
72057594037927936 2993 77.10689745322621
144115188075855872 2993 75.7541448663275
288230376151711744 13257 329.7553130528446
576460752303423488 3421 83.65185991323972
1152921504606846976 2994 71.99048254035928
2305843009213693952 3421 80.9091759816581
4611686018427387904 3421 79.60418927227651
```

As you can see, even for n = 2^62, the execution time is only 3421 nanoseconds, this is obviously not linear. The ratio `executionTime/log(n)` seem pretty stable at the end and is about 80, that makes your solution a `O(n)`.

I think the variations we observe at the beginning are due to the second term of the Fibonacci series. Indeed, `Fn = (phi^n - psi^n)/sqrt(5) with phi = (1 + sqrt(5))/2 > 1 and psi = (1 - sqrt(5))/2 < 1`. When n is small, `psi^n` still influences the result but because it is lower than 1, it gets very small when n is huge, which is why it gets logarithmic at the end and not right at the beginning.

Comment: is there any further optimization possible in it?

Comment: I didnt tried its runtime analysis.. but this problem gives me time lime exceed so I assumed that it would be o(n)....thanks for your suggestion .I  removed o(n) time complexity

Answer (score 1):

It's trivial to show that our target value is (*n* + *k*), where *F<sub>k</sub>* is the largest Fibonacci number that's smaller than our target.  Thus all we need to do is find *k*.

You can do this in O(log log n) time by using a binary search (with matrix multiplication).

You can do this in O(1) time by inverting the [closed-form expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Computation_by_rounding) for *F<sub>k</sub>* in terms of *k*.

Comment: How did you come up with the second complexity ? By doing this it seems to me you can compute Fn in O(1) but not finding the largest Fibonacci number smaller than n in constant time. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @Dici: I hadn't really thought about it, so it could be wrong.  But my assumption was that you could invert the expression, and pass in *n* (and then round the result).  This gives us *k'*, which in most cases will be equal to the desired *k*.  There are indeed cases where *Fk'* < *n* < *Fk* < *(n+k)* (i.e. we rounded to the wrong Fibonacci index, because *n < (n+k)*).  However, we know that *F(k'+1) - Fk' >> k* (in general).  So at most we need to check *Fk'* and *F(k'+1)*.  So still O(1).

Comment: I'm not sure, it certainly works with  very few code and it's a good idea, but evaluate the inverse in n has a cost (not sure what the complexity of computing a log is, for example, especially if the base is not 2). I +1 you anyway for the mathematical ideas :p

Comment: @Dici: Well, that enters the realm of asking what our machine model is.  In reality, none of the primitive operations here (addition, multiplication, log) are invariant of the word-size...

Comment: Right :) BTW, I would like to ask you a quick question, would you mind joining me on this chat room ? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84311/quick-chat